# Reload com.apple.Terminal.plist

Tags: macos, terminal, reload, defaults

I want use a script to modify the preferences of my terminal for my Mac, so it can close the window when exit the terminal. I use this command  in the script:

`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set \"Window Settings\":Basic:shellExitAction 0" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`

Now the problem is after execute the script, the .plist file is do changed, I check it by

`defaults read com.apple.Terminal "Window Settings"`

The value is 0 now.

But the problem is the terminal not reload the .plist file, and when I exit the terminal, it rewrite the .plist file as '2' again. So my question is how to let terminal reload the .plist file when it's running or stop it rewrite the file when it exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a classic chicken and egg problem to me.

Terminal writes out its current preferences upon quitting and overwrites any of your changes, yet you need Terminal loaded in order to have a shell to make those changes with PlistBuddy.

I can think of two solutions here:

1) write a small script that you can launch from a non-Terminal process... maybe an Applescript or something you can pass into a `system` call from a tiny Macintosh app?  :-)

2) simply change the "Settings" to what you desire by going to Terminal preferences.

Comment: I have run the script in xterm and it works now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok, I find another way to solve this. Just kill all Terminal process after the script. Because the terminal not exit in the normal way, it won't have change to write the .plist file.

Answer (score 10):

In 10.9 (Mavericks), preferences are cached. After overwriting your preferences from Terminal, you need to read them with

```
defaults read com.apple.Terminal
```

and then Quit and restart Terminal.

I have my Terminal preferences on my server, so the full command I use on a new machine or in a new profile is:

```
curl -o ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist  http://example.com/xyz/com.apple.Terminal.plist.`sw_vers \
| grep 'ProductVersion:' \
| grep -o '10\.[0-9]*'` \
&& defaults read com.apple.Terminal
```

Comment: This worked, though I had to use `defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` with the full path, rather than just `defaults read com.apple.Terminal`.

Answer (score 3):

My adapted solution runs in OS X Mavericks (too).

In the Example I add a new PermanentServer for a ssh connection in Terminal `-p 22 www.example.com -l user -L 33306:localhost:3306`

1. Close the Terminal-App
2. Open the plist-file in *Xcode* and edit the setting *PermanentServer* (copy and paste the string above)

   `open ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`
3. Save and close the plist-file
4. Open the Applescript-App and copy/paste/run following code:

   `do shell script "defaults read ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist"`
5. Open Terminal-App and press SHIFT+CMD+K and looks in the serverlist

Thanks for this hint here: http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-manually-edit-defaults-plist-files-in-mavericks/

Answer (score 3):

The "at" command can run a command sometime in the future.

```
$ at now + 1 minute
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set \"Window Settings\":Basic:shellExitAction 0" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
^D          <<< press CTRL-D
job 3 at Mon Apr 24 15:34:00 2017
$ exit
```

Now exit all terminals.  Wait 1 minute (at least).  Now start Terminal and you'll find the setting has been changed.